# Is is possible to cache external libraries in localStorage?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I was interested in doing this cross domain.

I want to some how get the source, after downloading and executing it with a

```
<script src = "libary_i_want_to_cache">
```

script tag, and put this source into localStorage.

```
localStorage.script_source = the_source;
```

I am aware of all the other caching mechanisms provided by such things as the browser but I want to store my script in localStorage in this particular case.

Is there a script tag parameter I can use?

I checked [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/script) but found none.  Is using cors relevant?

Thanks,

Comment: There is no way to get the external script that is included with the script tag. You will need to fetch it with an Ajax call.

Comment: You can't do this without ajax.  You can't retrieve the contents of a script tag directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, the browser would do caching for you, given the right cache headers from the server.

Also, there is what you call the [app cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Using_the_application_cache) which is more appropriate in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any way to do this without ajax.   The script tag itself does not offer access to the script source that it downloaded.

If your script is coming from the same domain as your web page and you are willing to use ajax, then you can use ajax to retrieve the text of the script and you can then store that text in local storage.

To load the script from local storage, you'd read the script from local storage into a string variable and then use `eval()` on it to parse/execute it.

All this said, it seems that the built-in caching mechanisms of the browser would be more appropriate unless you help us understand why they don't work for you.

Comment: First line: "*I was interested in doing this with out using ajax.*"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use localStorage to store javascript. setting innerHTML will execute the script content, but better way is setting to src using window.URL.createObjectURL.